# Call a function on Raspberry Pi Pico from PC using pyserial

Tags: python, pyserial, raspberry-pi-pico

I have a small python file in Raspberry Pi Pico that can control servos via PCA9685 servo controller:

```
import time
from adafruit_servokit import ServoKit
import busio
import board
import time
kit = ServoKit(channels=16, i2c=(busio.I2C(board.GP1, board.GP0)))

def rotateservo():
    kit.servo[0].angle = 100
    time.sleep(1)
    kit.servo[0].angle = 0
    time.sleep(1)
    kit.servo[0].angle = 180
```

The function works fine when called from Pico.
I am looking for a way to call the function from a PC using pyserial

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 115200, timeout=timeout)
ser.write('rotateservo()'.encode())
ser.close()
```

This simply outputs the number 13 which I assume is the length of the string. How do I call a function on Pi Pico using pyserial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do this. I have this running on a Pico W:

```
import select
import sys
from machine import Pin
import utime

gpio_no = 'LED'
led = Pin(gpio_no, Pin.OUT)

# setup poll to read USB port
poll_object = select.poll()
poll_object.register(sys.stdin,1)

def blink(length):
    led.value(1)
    utime.sleep(length)
    led.value(0)
    utime.sleep(0.2)
    
def function_1():
    print("Executing function 1")
    blink(0.2)

def function_2():
    print("Executing function 2")
    blink(0.2)
    blink(0.2)

blink(1)
print("Started looking")
while True:
    # check usb input
    if poll_object.poll(0):
        #read as character
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        if ch == "1":
            function_1()
        elif ch == "2":
            function_2()
        else:   
            print (ch, "Received. Was expecting 1 or 2")
            blink(1)
```

If it receives a '1' it executes function_1, which briefly flashes the LED once and also sends a message back. If it receives a '2' it briefly flashes the LED twice and sends an other message back. For all other characters it does a longer (1 second) flash, and sends a different message.

Here is the code to run in Python on a PC (replace COM7 with the port number you are using).

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600, write_timeout=0)

to_send = ['1', '2', '3']

for a in to_send:
    bytes_sent = ser.write(bytes(a, 'UTF-8'))
    print(f"Sent {bytes_sent} bytes ({a})")
    line = ser.readline()
    print(f"Received: {line.decode('UTF-8') }")
    time.sleep(1)

ser.close()

print("done")
```

It uses the pyserial module, and sends a '1', a '2' and a '3' at one second intervals. These are picked up by the Pico, which flashes in response, and sends text back to the PC confirming what it has received. This is the PC printout:

```
Sent 1 bytes (1)
Received: Executing function 1

Sent 1 bytes (2)
Received: Executing function 2

Sent 1 bytes (3)
Received: 3 Received. Was expecting 1 or 2

done
```

When setting this up you need to run the Pico program as main.py (running from the Pico). Once it is running you need to take Thonny off the serial port, or you will not be able to access it from the Python code. To do this, click on Thonny bottom-right, and set it to anything but the COM port you are using (for example 'Local Python').

Comment: Thanks. This works very well. The library does not give accurate rotation physically. For example, rotating to 180 degrees in the code will result in about 120 degrees of rotation only. Do you know a way to fix this?

Comment: This may be a hardware issue. Check the spec on your servo. Some have a max rotation of 120 degrees. Assuming yours can give a full rotation of 180 degrees, it apparently needs a pulse with range of from 500 to 2500. This is something that you can check with an ascilloscope or with a servo tester. If you set the rotation to 90 degrees, does it rotate the full 90 degrees?

Comment: If i rotate the servo manually, it can do a 180 rotation without problem. It seems the library does not allow full 180 degrees. Even a 90 degree rotation is more like a 70 degree one

Comment: I guess you would have to explore the spec of the library. Certainly checking with an ascilloscope or with a servo tester should tell you if the servo is being sent the right signals.